# Is there a way one could send ONE message to MANY numbers? [pywhatkit]

Tags: python, loops

I have been researching ways and means of having one message being sent to all users in a given list. The problem is, though, that when using a list with numbers and looping through them, it immediately fires up all three instances and sends message to only one of them. When adding "sleep", it only fires up one instance and then says "successful" even though it only sent a message to one out of two people.

```
# importing the module 
import pywhatkit 
import datetime 
import time  

nums = ["+1234","+5678"]  

try:          
    for c in nums:                 
        pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg(c, "Testing Automatic Whatsapp",xHour, yMinute, 20)
        print("Successfully Sent!")
        time.sleep(25)  

except:   
    print("An Unexpected Error!")
```

Therefore is there a way at all to send a message to multiple people? I have tried searching for this on SO and other places on Google, best I could find was just the addition of a loop but that was it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve it, basically we must close the browser process to be sending the next message to the next group, here is a code example:

```
lista_grupos = ['code_group1', 'code_group2']
            
for grupo in lista_grupos:
  #These variables are to avoid whatsapp banning by span
  time_sleep_msg = random.randint(60, 150)  # Time wait
  my_wait_time = random.randint(20, 60)
  my_close_time = random.randint(5, 20)
         
  pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_to_group_instantly(grupo, f'Your message', wait_time=my_wait_time, tab_close=True, close_time=my_close_time)

  sleep(5)
  try:
      os.system("taskkill /f /im chrome.exe")
      print('chrome close')
  except:
      print('chrome it was already closed')
  sleep(time_sleep_msg)
```